# Different sorting within groups crystal reports

Tags: sorting, crystal-reports

I have a report in Crystal Reports with multiple subreports and groups. The overall report is grouped by Incoming Loan Status (are the loans at the venue or upcoming, etc.) and then within that is grouped by the exhibition name and then the accession numbers.

I want to have the report sorted by Incoming Loan Status (which I have done) and within that loan status, the date. I need all loan statuses that are at the venue to be sorted in ascending order by the VenueCompletionDate (i.e. when it returns) and all loan statuses that are upcoming to be sorted in ascending order by the VenueCommencementDate.

I had looked at parameter sorts, but I need both at venue and upcoming loans on the same report and need both sorts to happen simultaneously within those groups.

Are there any recommendations for this?

[Link to example report](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jllonl73ahl73vi/Publicforumreport.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: Show some examples of the report and the desired output.

Comment: you probably need an independent variable to sort the way you want.  You'll need to create a formula named something like 'sortSequence' which contains your conditional logic for how to sort under the different conditions of the loan status.

Comment: I uploaded an example if that is of use.

Comment: So I can create a formula that is something like: If({eloans_csv.InfLoanStatusValue}="Approved/At Venue") then   {Venues.VenVenueCommencementDate} else   If({eloans_csv.InfLoanStatusValue}="Approved/Upcoming") then  
{Venues.VenVenueCompletionDate}? I wasn't sure how to properly write the syntax for this.